# Keras: Predictions not accurate

Tags: python, keras, prediction

I have a regression problem, where I am trying to predict a column `C` value (picture attached) from a excel sheet.

[image]

```
set_random_seed(7)

df = pd.read_excel("ABC_sheet.xlsx")

data = df.iloc[:, 0:2]
labels_column = df['C']

training_data = data
training_labels = labels_column
print("Creating the pickle_model ...")
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(300, input_dim=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(300, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(300, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(300, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

print("pickle_models Fitting ...")
model.fit(training_data, training_labels, epochs=20000, verbose=1)
print("Training has been completed successfully!")

# Expected Res: 0.00531548914829121
Xnew0 = np.array([[0.54, 0.63446746]])


# Expected Res: 6.34934075187519E-07
Xnew = np.array([[0.44, 0.37447464]])

# Expected Res: 0.0000628
Xnew2 = np.array([[0.53, 0.00063189]])

# Expected Res: 0.00531548914829121
Xnew3 = np.array([[0.54, 0.63446746]])


ynew = model.predict(Xnew0)
ynew2 = model.predict(Xnew)
ynew3 = model.predict(Xnew2)
ynew5 = model.predict(Xnew3)

print("Predicted1 =%s, Predicted2 =%s, Predicted3 =%s, Predicted4 =%s, Predicted4 =%s" % (ynew[0], ynew2[0], ynew3[0], ynew5[0]))
```

OUTPUT:

```
Predicted1 =[0.00591827], Predicted2 =[6.762405e-08], Predicted3 =[0.00139873], Predicted4 =[0.00591827]
```

The results are not near to the expected results. As `Predicted3 =[0.00139873]` should have been closer to `Expected Res: 0.0000628`

I tried using different number of layers/neurons as well. Any help?

EDITED:

```
def GetNormalizedValue(val, min, max):
    if val > max:
        val = max
    if val < min:
        val = min
    if min == max:
        return 0
    denominator = max - min
    numerator = float(val) - min
    value = numerator / denominator
    # print(value)
    return value

def NormalizeData(df):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        col_A = row['A']
        col_B = row['B']
        col_C = row['C']
        column_A = GetNormalizedValue(col_A, 0, 100)
        column_B = GetNormalizedValue(col_B, 0, 1000000)
        column_C = GetNormalizedValue(col_C, 1, 10000)
```

Comment: why are you using binary cross entropy loss, why not mse loss?

Comment: You should normalize input and outputs, and use a mean squared error loss.

Comment: I even tried with 'mse` @MatiasValdenegro the IN/OUT are normalized already?

Comment: Why do you ask if they are normalized already, that's something only you can answer.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I was telling you that they're normalized already.

Comment: They don't really look normalized, how exactly are you normalizing them?

Comment: hot encoded Column A since it previously had strings, Column B was normalized to a range of 0 - 1000000 since it defines the MB of data and Column C was normalized to range between 1 - 10000 using the Normalized method edited in the question

Comment: You should normalize the outputs to the [0, 1] range, same as the range of the sigmoid activation

Comment: That is within the range [0, 1]